# JQuery remove td with id contains even number

Tags: jquery

I have a table with counting row id like below:

```
<td class="text-center manage" id="sw-1" rowspan="2" width="20%">
<td class="text-center manage" id="sw-2" rowspan="2" width="20%">
<td class="text-center manage" id="sw-3" rowspan="2" width="20%">
<td class="text-center manage" id="sw-4" rowspan="2" width="20%">
<td class="text-center manage" id="sw-5" rowspan="2" width="20%">
<td class="text-center manage" id="sw-6" rowspan="2" width="20%">
<td class="text-center manage" id="sw-7" rowspan="2" width="20%">
<td class="text-center manage" id="sw-8" rowspan="2" width="20%">
```

for some reason, I want to play some 'dirt' work to use jquery remove these `td` with id contains even number, ideally output is:

```
<td class="text-center manage" id="sw-1" rowspan="2" width="20%">
<td class="text-center manage" id="sw-3" rowspan="2" width="20%">
<td class="text-center manage" id="sw-5" rowspan="2" width="20%">
<td class="text-center manage" id="sw-7" rowspan="2" width="20%">
```

I've try:

```
$('table td[id*="sw-"]').not(':even').remove();
```

but doesn't come the results I want.

please advise.

Comment: `$('tr td:even').remove()`

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Okay, you enlighten me, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
           var i=$('table td');
           console.log(i);
            $.each(i,function(k,v){
              var id=v.id.split('-');
                 if(id[1]%2 == 0){
                     $('#sw-'+id[1]).remove();
                 }
             });
         });
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td class="text-center manage" id="sw-1" width="20%">1</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="text-center manage" id="sw-2"  width="20%">2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td class="text-center manage" id="sw-3"  width="20%">3</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```